# Spring Data with Mongo: Subdocument name as query parameter

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have the following document structure:

```
{
    "_id": "project1",
    "customer": "someDefaultCustomer",
    "users": {
        "user1": {
            "projectRoles": ["CUSTOMER"]
        }
    }
}
```

Now i'm going to query all projects with user contain 'user1' with Spring Data Mongo:

```
@Query("{'users.?1': {$exists : true} }")
Project findUserProject(String login);
```

The problem is that Spring Data escapes replacement in queries, so i've got the following 'real' query:

o.s.d.m.r.q.StringBasedMongoQuery - Created query `{ "users.\"user1\"" : { "$exists" : true}}`

Is it possible to avoid escaping? Of course, i can create custom query using spring criteria, but i'd like to keep '@Query' approach.

Comment: I don't know about Spring Data but if you want to match every documents that contains user1. the query in Mongo db should be

Answer (score 0):

Pass in the full users.user1 as the variable, i.e.:

```
@Query("{?1: {$exists : true} }")
```

If you really want to avoid people having to do that then have a helper function that adds the "users." at the start of the string then calls this method.